# Listing all friends and joining to the users table

Tags: php, mysql, database, social-networking

I have a database named 'friends' and it has columns 'user_id' and 'friend_id'.
user_id is the invitor and friend_id the recipient. Please note that when a friendship is created I'm NOT making 2 records in the database like 1,2 and 2,1.

How to list all the friends of mine, considering that my users.user_id can vary between friends.friend_id and friends.user_id in the 'friends' table. Also how to join the query to the 'users' table to get the names of all my friends.

Comment: my partner is testing right now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be a union of two queries:

```
select u.name
    from friends f
        inner join users u
            on f.user_id = u.user_id
    where f.friend_id = @YourID
union
select u.name
    from friends f
        inner join users u
            on f.friend_id = u.user_id
    where f.user_id = @YourID
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make a **Join query** to get the best performance. Try something like this:

```
$friends_result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        users.`name` AS name
    FROM
        friends
    LEFT JOIN
        users
    ON
        users.`id` = friends.`user_id`
    OR
        users.`id` = friends.`friend_id`
    AND
        users.`id` != '" . $user_id . "'
    WHERE
        friends.`user_id` = '" . $user_id . "'
    OR
        friends.`friend_id` = '" . $user_id . "'");

echo "<strong>My friends:</strong><br />";

while($friends_array = mysql_fetch_array($friends_result))
{
    echo $friends_array['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: it's working but we are curious about Archimedix's approach and will vote for best answer later :)

Comment: Here's just one problem. This query returns every time the id of the friend and my own id. If I have 200 friends it will return them and also 200 times my id.

Comment: How do you mean? There is only one field in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think it would probably be easiest to ensure that the `friends` table always has the lower ID in the `user_id` column and the higher one in the other.

This way, you do not need to check twice, thus achieving better performance.</strike>

However, this approach requires you to modify your friend-adding code and assumes that user IDs never change (or you have to update your IDs in the table).

Otherwise, use `UNION` queries like Joe said or to join using an `OR` condition (e.g. `JOIN ... ON u.user_id = friends.user_id OR u.user_id = friends.friend_id`) or `IN` (`JOIN ... ON u.user_id IN (friends.user_id, friends.friend_id)`), which might be expensive operations (use `EXPLAIN` and benchmarks to find out).

Comment: This approach is very interesting but we don't quite get it. Do you mean something like 
2 | 5,
2 | 4,
4 | 5                                                                     and if so how this excludes the second check and simplifies the query?

Comment: Duh... sorry, looks like I just had some weird thinking going... ignore the first part for the answer, that would require you to store the reverse relation as well (`2 | 5` and `5 | 2`) and requires an additional flag, or an additional query condition to work. Then, you would only fetch those relations where `user_id` is less than `friend_id` in the table, avoiding duplicates. However, this is probably not faster than the other approaches.